# Get report name from DataSource of subform ms access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, report

I have a form (say form1) to navigate to another form (form2) which has a subform that opens reports based on the DataSource put into by selecting the Text box on form1.

The code looks like this

```
Private Sub txt_DeliveryItemsSummary_Click()
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_viewReports", acNormal
        Forms!frm_ViewReports!subrpt_ReportArea.SourceObject = "Report.rpt_DeliveryItemsSummary"
End Sub
```

And on form2 I have a print button to print the report
The code looks like this

```
    DoCmd.OpenReport subrpt_ReportArea.SourceObject, acViewNormal, , , acWindowNormal
```

But this code gives following error

[Runtime Error 2103](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwsr3.png)

The report name 'Report.rpt_DeliveryItemsSummary' you entered in either the property sheet or macro is misspelled or refers to a report that doesn't exist.

Any help how can I fix this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with `Forms!frm_ViewReports!subrpt_ReportArea.SourceObject = "rpt_DeliveryItemsSummary"`?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks @Gustav! You have helping earlier as well.
I did try with this but then it does not open the report on the form 
it gives runtime error 2101. The setting you entered isn't valid for this property. 
To open the report i must go with the code like this
 
Forms!frm_ViewReports!subrpt_ReportArea.SourceObject = "Report.rpt_DeliveryItemsSummary"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out myself. I knew i need to skip a piece of text but how! There I was getting trouble.

Here is the working code

```
    DoCmd.OpenReport Right(subrpt_ReportArea.SourceObject, Len(subrpt_ReportArea.SourceObject) - 7), , acViewNormal, , , acWindowNormal
```

Thanks @Gustav for reaching out again.